# chromium-headless installed path in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, chromium

I have installed `chromium-headles`s in *CentOS 7* by :

```
Installed latest-epel-release  then
yum install chromium-headless


[root@localhost chromedriver]# yum list installed | grep chromium
chromium-common.x86_64           60.0.3112.113-2.el7               @epel
chromium-headless.x86_64         60.0.3112.113-2.el7               @epel
```

I need to mention the `chromium-headless` installed path in `Globalproperities.properities` file (*Apache Maven*).

How to find its installed path in the server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Files were located in :

```
/usr/lib64/chromium-browser/headless_shell
```

Comment: i use the default path `/usr/bin/chromium-browser` and Puppeteer launches it in headless mode by default

Answer (score 2):

@Soundar Try finding with

> ps -ef | grep chromium

You will able to view the path